# How to parse arraylist data sent from servlet into JSON in Jquery

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, servlets

I am using servlet to sent data as arraylist to ajax calls.Now on client side i am trying to parse that data into json type but it is giving error as..

**SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character var dbdata=JSON.parse(data);**

The values that i am getting ajax success is

**[INCOMING, 0, INETCALL, 0, ISD, 31.8, LOCAL, 197.92, STD, 73.2]**

Here is my client side ajax code..

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'getdata',
            async:false,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {

                var dbdata=JSON.parse(data);
                alert(dbdata);
            }
        });
   });
```

and here is my servlet code..

```
ArrayList callcost = new ArrayList();

    try {
        String strQuery = "";
        ResultSet rs = null;

        Conexion conexiondb = new Conexion();
        conexiondb.Conectar();

        strQuery = "SELECT toc,Sum(callcost) as callcost FROM `asteriskcdrdb`.`processeddata_table` group by toc";

        rs = conexiondb.Consulta(strQuery);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String toc = rs.getString("toc").trim();
            String cost=rs.getString("callcost").trim();
            callcost.add(toc.trim());
            callcost.add(cost.trim());
        }

        out.print(callcost);
        System.out.println(callcost);
        out.close();
```

Please guys help me .
Thanks in advance..

Comment: interesting variable names `callcost` , `calllcost`

Comment: @melc i changed the variable name sir .please check the post

Comment: You don't parse into JSON, you parse *from* JSON. You have a JSON string which you parse to get a JavaScript object or array; the opposite function is `stringify`, which takes a JavaScript object or array and returns the JSON string representation of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say this is what AJAX returns:

```
[INCOMING, 0, INETCALL, 0, ISD, 31.8, LOCAL, 197.92, STD, 73.2]
```

The strings are invalid for JSON; it should be:

```
["INCOMING", 0, "INETCALL", 0, "ISD", 31.8, "LOCAL", 197.92, "STD", 73.2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and write code like,

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(callcost);
```

this will allow you to support more complex objects as well.
Or you can build it yourself as Nikos mentioned.