# Return arraylist as object from action Class to jsp in Java Using Ajax?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, arraylist

How do i return an ArrayList from Acton To JSP Using Ajax. I am able to fetch values from database and iterate and store the same in an ArrayList. But i am not sure of how do i return the list from Action and iterate the same in JSP Code.
Please find the below code

**Action Class:**

```
    public ActionForward fetchValues(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
    try 
    {   
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        List coordinateList=new ArrayList();
        Connection con;
        String link=request.getParameter("test");
        con = DriverManager .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:----/testDatabase", "test","test1");
        String sql="select placeNames from line_route where gid='"+test+"'";
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next())
        {
            String str = rs.getString(1);
            str = str.replaceAll("\\(", "");

            String[] a = str.split(",");
            for (String b : a) 
            {
                System.out.println("-" + b + "-");
                coordinateList.add(b);
            }
        }
        out.println(coordinateList);
        return null;

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Exception!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

return null;
}
```

**JSP Code:**

```
function fetchValues()
{
var id=document.getElementById('linkNo').value;
initRequest();  
req.open("POST", "./sendLinks.do?actionMethod=fetchValues&link="+id, true);   
req.send(null); 
}

  var req; 
    function initRequest() 
    {    
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {    
            req = new XMLHttpRequest();    
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {    
            isIE = true;    
            req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");    
        }    
    }
```

Request you all to please guide as how do i fetch the list in JSP and iterate in javascript code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Arraylist is class and what you trying is to get an object as response of ajax. It is not possible to retrieve an object as ajax response. You can get the arraylist in your page by putting that in your session or by using Gson.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your arrayList to java script array using JSON

you can write this javascript function inside a JSP page ( after reading the list from response)

```
var varlist= <%=net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(coordinateList) %>;
```

If you want to use pure AJAX, I would suggest to return XML data as response, and you can parse ,see below helpful link

[How to parse arraylist data sent from servlet into JSON in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836737/how-to-parse-arraylist-data-sent-from-servlet-into-json-in-jquery)